# Must a bundle be resolved for its exported packages to become available?

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

I have two bundles A and B.

- A exports package packA
- B imports packA

This means that B depends on A, but only to get one package. Now A has further dependencies that are *not* fulfilled, so in the running system bundle A is only *installed* but not *resolved*.

Can Bundle B become *resolved* in the running system? It doesn't need bundle A, only one of its packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. A bundle must be resolved to export or import packages or even have a class loader.